# Creating an auto updating Windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-10, windows-services, auto-update

I'm trying to create a service that can update itself using .NET Core 3.1.  I've tried running an installer I downloaded but later found out that Windows services don't interact with the desktop.  It also doesn't run any executable or commands (creating a file).

I've researched and found posts from 10 years ago but none of the solutions that was offered worked.

Does anyone have a solution that works on Windows 10 and 8?

Comment: Did you try a task taht executes an update script? Or a shell service that dynamically loads the version? it IS possible - lots of systems do it, among them i.e. an "as service" aure devops build agent.

Comment: @TomTom I haven't tried any of them; I'll give them a try.  I was hoping to develop it within the same service.

Comment: Even if the linked question is old and some solutions may be out of date, the overall idea still applies, so you can get some value out of it.

Comment: I was able to create an auto updater by making a scheduled task.